# Get a single SNMP value with pysnmp

Tags: python, pysnmp

I'm trying to get the value of a single OID into a variable. However, I only am able to walk it using `pysnmp`.
I want to get the value of OID `1.3.6.1.4.1.2.3.51.2.2.7.1.0` which returns value 255 if I test it using an SNMP tool.

Using this code I don't get any output:

```
def getsnmp(host, oid):

    for (errorIndication,
         errorStatus,
         errorIndex,
         varBinds) in nextCmd(SnmpEngine(),
                              CommunityData('public', mpModel=0),
                              UdpTransportTarget((host, 161)),
                              ContextData(),
                              ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(oid)),
                              lookupMib=False,
                              lexicographicMode=False):

        if errorIndication:
            print(errorIndication)
            break

        elif errorStatus:
            print('%s at %s' % (errorStatus.prettyPrint(),
                                errorIndex and varBinds[int(errorIndex) - 1][0] or '?'))
            break

        else:
            for varBind in varBinds:
                print(' = '.join([x.prettyPrint() for x in varBind]))

getsnmp('10.100.11.30', '1.3.6.1.4.1.2.3.51.2.2.7.1.0')
```

However, If I remove the last .0, I get as a result:

> 1.3.6.1.4.1.2.3.51.2.2.7.1.0 = 255

How do I access the specific OID directly without a walk?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `nextCmd` returns the *next* OID relative to the given one. It never returns the value for the given OID.

If you need to query specific OID you should use `getCmd` function instead of `nextCmd`.